# AWS Lambda: Getting error again and again in Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using AWS for my app development. I am using a python lambda function in AWS.

This lambda function gets triggered when any item is modified in dynamodb table `mytable`.

I modified the item 2 hours ago. I changed its value from 4 to 5. And **even after 2 hours** I am still getting the error (right now also) in cloudwatch logs:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'OldImage'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in lambda_handler
    if (event['Records'][itert]['dynamodb']['NewImage']['amount']['S'] != event['Records'][itert]['dynamodb']['OldImage']['amount']['S']):
```

The surprising thing is that the error logs are coming again and again in the cloudwatch even after 2 hours since when I have stopped modifying items in dynamodb table. Why is that?

Comment: From lambda metrics, how many invocations had your function in the last 2 hours?

Comment: @OmarRosadio From the lambda metrics I see that for the last 3 hours - The graph shows a horizontal line of count 1.

Comment: 1 invocation every period of 5 minutes?

Comment: @OmarRosadio I think it is getting invoked continuously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MaximumRetryAttempts parameter from Event Source Mapping Configuration.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_EventSourceMappingConfiguration.html):

> MaximumRetryAttempts
> (Streams only) Discard records after the specified number of retries. The default value is -1, which sets the maximum number of retries to infinite. When MaximumRetryAttempts is infinite, Lambda retries failed records until the record expires in the event source.

[image: Event Source Mapping Configuration]

With the default value, the function will retry to process the event indefinitely (until the records expire or exceed the maximum age that you configure on the event source mapping). You need to set an appropriate value according to your use case.

Comment: Hmmm. I see that in my AWS lambda, under the `dynamodb` trigger, the retry attempts is set to -1. How do I change this? I also can't find the option to change retry attempts in `dynamodb` streams

Comment: Where is the option to change retry attempts ?

Comment: Delete the trigger and then re-create it